# Status based on state in daemon mode

Tags: optaplanner

I have daemon mode enabled, and when I run `getSolverStatus()` it returns `SOLVING_ACTIVE` regardless if the solver is in blocked state or running state.

Is there a way for me to explicitly know what state the solver is currently in?

The reason behind is I want to display idle for blocked state and processing for running state on my frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solver status doesn't change in this case as the solver running in daemon mode does not terminate unless you call `terminateEarly()`.

Why is it important to know if the solver running in daemon mode is actively improving the solution or not?

The daemon mode is used together with `ProblemChange`s. After a `ProblemChange` has been incorporated into the working solution, a new best solution is passed to the caller. See the [`SolverManager.addProblemChange()`](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/SolverManager.html#addProblemChange(ProblemId_,org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.change.ProblemChange)) for more details.

However, there is no guarantee when and if some next more optimal solution is produced. You can wait a fixed amount of time before you publish the solution if a new one does not come, for instance.